# Unknown characters while printing map of two char pointer in set

Tags: c++, mysql

Here Is My Code

```
set<map<char*, char*>> AllRows;
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
    map<char*, char*> abc;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        abc.insert(pair<char*, char*>(azColName[i], argv[i]));
    }
    AllRows.insert(abc);
    for (auto row : AllRows) {
        for (auto it : row) {
            cout << it.first << "\t" << it.second << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    } // Always Works
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //SomeBasic Setup
    string Command = "SELECT * FROM Company";
    const char* sta = "";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, Command.c_str(), callback,(void*)sta,&ErrMsg);
    if (rc!=SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << ErrMsg;
        sqlite3_free(ErrMsg);
    }
    for (auto row : AllRows) {
        for (auto it : row) {
            cout << it.first << "\t" << it.second << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }//Showing Different set of char everytime

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

In this i want to save all information of data in a set. But when I run for each in callback function it works while if run foreach in main function it doesn't prints but some weird character. The Size of set is correct ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings that the pointers in the callback function are pointing to is managed by the SQLite code, not by your program. SQLite can reuse the memory or simply `free` it (if it was dynamically allocated).

If you need to use that data outside of the callback function you *must* copy them. For example by using `std::string` for both the key and data in the map:

```
map<string, string> abc;
```